# C# Mute Audio Selenium Chrome Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Like my title says, I am looking for a way to mute any audio on Selenium Chrome Web Driver.

I found this for python(example below) and was wondering if there was something similar for C#?

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("mute-audio");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I was looking for!